# Can't find owner's tokens with Metaplex

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, getprogramaccounts

I'm working on a front-end. I want to fetch all the NFT of a specific collection the user owns.
I used to do:

```
const tokens = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .findAllByOwner({ owner: provider.publicKey });
```

But I recently noticed this returned an empty array even though the wallet I'm using has the tokens.
To bypass this issue, I started using `getProgramAccounts` like so to get it to work properly:

```
const mints = (
  await provider.connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(
    provider.publicKey,
    { programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID }
  )
).value
  .filter((e) => e.account.data.parsed.info.tokenAmount.uiAmount === 1)
  .map((e) => new PublicKey(e.account.data.parsed.info.mint));
const accounts: (Nft | null)[] = (
  await Promise.all(
    mints.map(async (e) => {
      try {
        return (await metaplex
          .nfts()
          .findByMint({ mintAddress: e })) as any;
      } catch {
        return null;
      }
    })
  )
).filter(Boolean);
```

Is there an explanation for this?
Is there a way to make the old expression work? It's much more compact and easier to read.

Comment: did you add a check if provider.publicKey is not equal to undefined ?

Comment: Yes I do and the other way of fetching data works.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be a provider error: I switched from using Alchemy provider to Helius and it now works as expected.